# PySpark CSV Rounding Issue

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am comparing two values, one from JSON and other from CSV.

Json value = 9159613164437314.0

CSV value = 9159613164437312.0

I have specified both as double datatypes()

( If I check manually, In CSV also it is summing up  9159613164437314.0, but when read through pyspark, it is rounding off automatically)

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: Can you try DecimalType or LongType?

Comment: Tried no luck still giving incorrect results

Comment: how is pyspark rounding the resulting number? both of them don't seem to have any decimals. maybe, try `bigint` type